# Android : ProgressDialog for a particular fragment or view?

Tags: android, android-fragments, progressdialog, mask

While we initialize the Progress Dialog we will provide the respective activity in the constructor and `setCancelable(false);` to resist the user(mask) to work while loading.

My question is that whether we can restrict the user to work in some particular view/fragment, while the user can work with other views and fragments.

Example is given here

Sample Image
[image: Sample Image]

In this image as you can see the user cannot click anything inside the toprun fragment, while the user can work outside it (Ex. can click highscore, play, boost etc..).

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the bounderies of your progressBar to your view's limits with these properties in your layout (xml)

```
android:layout_alignBottom="@id/yourViewID"
android:layout_alignLeft="@id/yourViewID"
android:layout_alignRight="@id/yourViewID"
android:layout_alignTop="@id/yourViewID"
```

After adjusting, play with margins, padding visibility or whatever you need...

I hope this helps!!

Comment: Creating ProgressDialog programatically  not progress bar

Comment: augh... I misunderstood you because of your sample and the similarity of the spell of the two words. In my opinion, the easiest and more useful way to do it is defining yourself your own layout (a textview and a pair of buttons inside a RelativeLayout) and inflate it wherever you want... by adjusting  its bouderies like I told you in my answer. This workaround could be useful because you will be able to reuse your component only inflating it in your new Activity. Sorry for my previous mistake